# ProgressBar not working

Tags: android, progress-bar

I got a circular `ProgressBar`.

I want the circular not to rotate, but to fill in. Like say maxvalue is 100... let's say s`etprogress(10)` then 10 % of the progress bar is colored... and so on

how can this be done? How can I handle it? it keeps rotating over and over....

**progress_bar.xml**

```
  <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar"
    android:max="100" />
```

progress_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:pivotX="50%"
   android:pivotY="50%"> 
  <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="4"
       android:thicknessRatio="48" android:useLevel="false">
       <size android:width="18dip" android:height="18dip" />
       <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
              android:startColor="#52c1b1" android:centerColor="#52c1b1"
              android:endColor="#ffffff" android:centerY="0.50" />
 </shape>
</animated-rotate>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not direct way to achieve what you want. The only way, AFAIK, is to have a custom `ProgressBar` and override `onDraw`. Through the canvas you get as parameter you can draw an arc, for instance representing the percentage of your progress.